# Como atribuir o valor de uma coluna do Excel em um comando SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, microsoft-excel, odbc

Consegui conectar ao meu Banco de Dados MySQL via ODBC, e exibir as informações que necessito via comando SQL, porém gostaria que o conteúdo de determinada célula da minha planilha estivesse nessa consulta SQL, consigo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exibir apenas o nome do cliente de acordo com o chamado "1016762", o que gostaria era que no comando sql estivesse algo assim:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM `otrs`.`ticket` where `tn` = A7
```

Onde A7 seria a célula da planilha onde conteria o mesmo valor de "1016762", porém pelo que pesquisei eu teria que passar isso pelo botão parâmetros, porém o mesmo não fica habilitado pra mim

Comment: Na guia dados do Excel selecione outras fontes e em seguida Do Microsoft Query. Lá você vai conseguir montar uma consulta idêntica às feitas no MS Access e referenciar os parâmetros nas células desejadas.

Comment: Quando fizer a consulta no Microsoft Query, terá de colocar um filtro em alguma coluna, este filtro, se não me engano deve ser por exemplo `codigo[]` e então quando fechar a consulta, será apresentado esta tela do seu print com o botão `parâmetros..`. ativado. Daí é só escolher a célula com o valor. Eu colocar uma resposta aqui seria como um tutorial com vários prints e isso não fica legal no site.

Comment: E por qual motivo você considera isso algo ruim? Acredito que seria muito mais fácil até para os próximos que tenham essa mesma dúvida, para entender como resolver o problema

Comment: Vou preparar e responderei ainda hoje.

Comment: Só para constar, consegui criar a conexão porém o botão "Parâmetros" em "Propriedades da conexão" sempre aparece desabilitado. Não sei se é por ali que consigo atribuir valores de células do excel na consulta sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui liberar o botão de **Parâmetro** nas **Propriedades da conexão** alterando meu comando SQL para isso:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM `otrs`.`ticket` where (tn = ?)
```

Assim ao tentar executar o comando uma janela é aberta para solicitar o parâmetro que será usado na *Query*

Encontrei essa dica nesse [fórum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/332d3169-2011-47af-8164-2667ae8287dc/consulta-sql-com-clula-excel-de-parmetro?forum=officept)

Comment: Quando você abre as propriedades da conexão, e em seguida o botão parâmetros, tem uma opção que é obter o valor da célula. Inclusive uma opção de atualizar ao alterar a célula.

Comment: Sim, mas para habilitar o botão "Parâmetros" é necessário que na *Query* esteja com um dos itens com **?**